# How to make a cross staff arpeggio with arrow on lilypond

Tags: code-snippets, notation, lilypond

i'm transcribing a score and I need to make a cross staff arpeggio with an arrow like this:

[image]

I tried using with this:

```
\version "2.20.0"

\score{
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "up" {
      {
    \set PianoStaff.connectArpeggios = ##t
    \arpeggioArrowUp
    <e' g'' c''>1\arpeggio\fermata \bar "|."
      }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
      {
    \clef F
    \arpeggioArrowUp
    <c c,>1\arpeggio_\fermata
      }
    }
  >>
}
```

but it doesn't work. I have searched on different snippets but I can't find anything.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: This question is more appropriately a question for music.stackexchange.com. Something like: https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/71392/how-to-notate-piano-cross-staff-glissando-with-pedal-line

Answer (score 4):

see [Arrow on cross-staves arpeggio](http://lilypond.1069038.n5.nabble.com/Arrow-on-cross-staves-arpeggio-td199328.html#a199332)
Code taken from there. It works.

```
\version "2.20.0"

arpeggioArrowUp = {
  \revert PianoStaff.Arpeggio.stencil
  \revert PianoStaff.Arpeggio.X-extent
  \override PianoStaff.Arpeggio.arpeggio-direction = #UP
}
\score{
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "up" {
      {
    \set PianoStaff.connectArpeggios = ##t
    \arpeggioArrowUp
    <e' g'' c''>1\arpeggio\fermata \bar "|."
      }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
      {
    \clef F
    \arpeggioArrowUp
    <c c,>1\arpeggio_\fermata
      }
    }
  >>
}
```

Answer (score 2):

And that can be shortened to this (especially at the end of a piece):

```
\version "2.20.0"

\score{
  \new PianoStaff <<
    \new Staff = "up" {
      {
    \set PianoStaff.connectArpeggios = ##t
    \once \override PianoStaff.Arpeggio.arpeggio-direction = #UP
    <e' g'' c''>1\arpeggio\fermata \bar "|."
      }
    }
    \new Staff = "down" {
      {
    \clef F
    <c c,>1\arpeggio_\fermata
      }
    }
  >>
}
```